# Azure Service Bus Binding causes Worker Role to become unhealthy after single fault

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I've been working on a Azure worker role that hosts a `netTcpRelayBinding` WCF service.  All seems to work well until One of my connected hosts disconnects unexpectedly.  Over the next couple of minutes, the role consistently loses stability and then reports itself as unhealthy.

I'm not sure where I should be looking.  I've got IntelliTrace enabled, and I've got some exceptions, which start with the `TimeoutException` you'd expect, but then continue on.  I get these messages:

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException - Inactivity timeout of (00:00:10) has been exceeded.

System.InvalidProgramException - The Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

After this, I get a series of communication exceptions, timeoutexceptions, and then eventually the whole host crashes with an OutOfMemoryException.

Things to note:  I've got 1 client connected.  No other calls or activity.  When he disconnects unexpectedly, the above consistently happens.

Tried catching the servicehost `Faulted` but that seemed to do nothing (can't see where it was hit in IntelliTrace logs.

Any ideas on where I should be looking?  Surely I don't need to recreate the service every time something like this happens right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't sound familiar. Can you reproduce this and how's your role feeling overall, meaning what's the CPU load looking like and what else is going on in parallel?

Cheers,
Clemens

Comment: I've got 3 other services running, all basicHttpBinding, all occassionally receiving calls from this same client.  But, those go all day long without error or significant CPU usage. This netTcpRelaybinding consistently causes the failure of the role (under the condition where the client is terminated unexpectedly).

Comment: That's fairly odd. If you haven't turned on WCF tracing already, I would suggest that you do and look at the resulting logs in the trace viewer looking for exceptions. If that doesn't get you anywhere, collect whatever you can collect in terms traces/logs, zip it up, and send it to me. I'm clemensv at microsoft.com

Comment: I'm not ready to call it just yet, but I may have an answer.  This only happens with IntelliTrace enabled.  I switched to profiling to confirm expected CPU, and suddenly couldn't reproduce.  I've just switched back to IntelliTrace, and it's failing again.  In a roundabout way your suggestion to check the CPU may have lead me to the answer.

Comment: That ended up being the solution the best I can tell.  I'm not sure what specifically about IntelliTrace caused the issue, but turning it off definitely resolves it.